display:block property is getting added automatically to default tab when some other tab has been made active on conditional basis
I am working in JSP. I do have the requirement to show third tab of my page as active instead of first tab if the url has the word "matrix".
Current URL : http://localhost:9080/ccsLab/myLab#matrix
JSP Code:
<div class="reportTabs actcontentz">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab-values">
<li id="lab1" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lab1">
<spring:message code="label.lab1" /></a></li>
<li id="lab2"><a data-toggle="tab" style="white-space: nowrap;" href="#lab2">
<spring:message code="label.lab2" /></a></li>
<li id="lab3"><a data-toggle="tab" style="white-space: nowrap;" href="#lab3">
<spring:message code="label.lab3" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

 <div class="tab-content">
 <div id="lab1" class="tab-pane active">
 <p> Inside lab 1 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="lab2" class="tab-pane fade">
 <p> Inside lab 2 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="lab3" class="tab-pane fade">
 <p> Inside lab 3 </p>
 </div>
 </div>

I tried using the below updated code on page load:
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("matrix") > -1) { 
    $('ul.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active').addClass('fade');

    $('ul.nav-tabs li').eq(2).addClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane').eq(2).addClass('active').removeClass('fade');
    } 
    })

I am able to activate the third tab and see its content also. But first tab content is still taking up the space at the top of page. So, a lot of white blank space is displayed on the page. And hence the content of third tab is displaying at the bottom, instead of how it should come on a fresh page. After debugging find out that display property is set as block for the first tab. I tried to forcibly make it as none, but style property is not getting changed.
Code:
$('.tab-pane').attr("style", "display: none !important");

Relevant CSS:
.actcontentz ul.nav-tabs li{
    top: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
    border-left: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
    border-right: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
}

.actcontentz ul.nav-tabs li a{ 
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #333 !important;
    border: none;
    margin-right:0px !important;
    border-radius:0px !important;
}

.actcontentz ul.nav-tabs li a span, .2actcontent button span{
    margin-right: 5px ;
}

.actcontentz ul.nav-tabs li.active a{
    background-color: rgba(152, 199, 232, 1) !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
     margin-right:0px !important;
     font-weight: bold;
    font-family: candara;
}
.actcontentz ul.nav-tabs li.active{
    background-color: rgba(152, 199, 232, 1);
    color: #fff !important;
    width: 140px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-right:2px !important;
    top: 1px !important;
}

Except for the first tab this CSS is getting applied to all the tabs. Can anyone please guide me on what's stopping the new CSS to be applied to the first tab. Thanks.

What steps have you taken to debug this? Have you logged what window.location.href actually contains?

Do you have any errors in the console?

@mykaf, - yes i tried debugging and logging. Control is going inside if condition, and coming on next 2 lines also. But still tab is not getting activated. And there are no errors in console also.

I think $("ul.tabs li") should be $("ul.nav-tabs li")

@NandhaKumarGandhi Yes, the condition might be wrong, either no one in the window.location.href has a matrix word. So, the tab may be activated if you put it in the else condition.

What constitutes "getting activated"? What does the relevant CSS look like?

@mykaf, Getting activated means, on page load by default first tab is active and its content is visible, but as per the requirement if redirection has happened from a different page and URL contains that extra word, then instead of first tab, third tab should be active and its content should be visible to the user.

Please include the relevant CSS; even if the included code works correctly, the active class won't change anything.

@mykaf, Added. Please check.

With the current code, I can see the contents of all tabs.

@mykaf, content of all tabs are visible. You have not read my description properly. I said when we are activating the third tab, then content of first tab is still taking up the space in third tab, because from somewhere it is inheriting display:block property by default.

With the code you have shown so far, I don't get any tab functionality at all. Is this relying on some additional framework, like Bootstrap, and you failed to mention that, perhaps?

@CBroe,  yes. Bootstrap is used in the project.

Then you should really rather use the JavaScript method Bootstrap provides for showing tabs.

I have used jQuery addClass and removeClass methods. Can you elaborate your explanation.
